# Javascript constructor calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux

Hi so in the app I am working on, I have this constructor that checks the redux store for error messages being passed by various components.  It displays the error or success messages just fine.  However once the user dismisses the banner (by clicking x) and I go to another person's portfolio the banner no longer shows error or success messages

```
constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
  store
  .select(StatusBannerState)
  .map(data => {
    return data.status_banner;
  })
  .subscribe(banner_state => {
    if (banner_state.success_list.length > 0) {
      this.showBanner = true;
      this.bannerMessage = this.createSuccessBannerMessage(
        banner_state.success_list
      );
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.store.dispatch(new BannerDimissesSuccessMessage());
        this.bannerMessage = this.createErrorBannerMessage(
          banner_state.error_list
        );
      }, 5000);
    } else if (banner_state.error_list.length > 0) {
      this.bannerMessage = this.createErrorBannerMessage(
        banner_state.error_list
      );
    } else {
      this.showBanner = false;
      this.bannerMessage = '';
    }
  });
}
```

I have this test function at the moment which I call in the createErrorMessage function to show or hide the funciton (I call it in the HTML component of the angular app)

```
showOrHideBanner(errorWidget) {
  errorWidget.length === 0
   ? (this.showBanner = false)
   : (this.showBanner = true);
}
```

I have another method that clears the redux store on initialization

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(new UserDismissesEverything());
}
```

What would be the best way to check for error messages again after the user has dismissed the banner

update: code for close

```
onCloseClick() {
  this.close.emit(true);
  this.show = false;
  this.clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
}
```

HTML component code

```
<div class="mt-1 container">
    <div class="alert-box">
    <div *ngIf="bannerMessage" class="px-3 mb-1">
                    <glass-alert-box
                        (close)="hideTheBanner()"
                      [success]="bannerMessageType == 'success'">{{ bannerMessage}}
                    </glass-alert-box>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try by using `ngAfterViewInit()` ?

Comment: No, I didn't try that.  I am really new to angular so I had no idea.  How would I go about using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
constructor(private store: Store<State>) {

}

ngOnInint() {
    this.store.dispatch(new UserDismissesEverything());
}

ngAfterViewInint() {
    this.store.select(StatusBannerState).map(data => {
        return data.status_banner;
    }).subscribe(banner_state => {
        if (banner_state.success_list.length > 0) {
            this.showBanner = true;
            this.bannerMessage = this.createSuccessBannerMessage(banner_state.success_list);
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.store.dispatch(new BannerDimissesSuccessMessage());
                this.bannerMessage = this.createErrorBannerMessage(banner_state.error_list);
            }, 5000);
        } else if (banner_state.error_list.length > 0) {
            this.bannerMessage = this.createErrorBannerMessage(banner_state.error_list);
        } else {
            this.showBanner = false;
            this.bannerMessage = '';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Also are you calling `this.store.dispatch(new UserDismissesEverything());` when user dismiss the dialog by clicking on `close` icon? If not, you will have to do that.

Comment: Thanks Anshuman,  Appreciate the help.  However the banner just doesn't appear again once the X icon is clicked.  Right now I am just calling a simple method this.showBanner = false; After that, the banner just vanishes

Comment: accidental reply nm

Comment: @sharsart you missed `this.showBanner = true;` in `else if` ?

Comment: nope still nothing.  It doesn't show the success or the error messages once the banner is closed.

Comment: updated the original post with the code for close click.

Comment: So I made a small change to the HTML component, instead of *ngIf=bannerMessage, I changed toe *ngIf=showBanner===true.  It seems to be working fine but i need to run more tests

Comment: @sharsart great !!